# How to SET value to NULL in integer column in case of empty input

Tags: postgresql

When I am trying to use following update query...

```
UPDATE
            product_table
        SET
            product_name = $1,
            price = $2,
            delivery_interval = NULLIF ($3, '')
        WHERE
            id = $4;
```

...following appears...

```
error: column "delivery_interval" is of type integer but expression is of type text
```

`delivery_interval = NULL` instead of `NULLIF ($3, '')` seems to work. Why?

Comment: What type is `$3`?

Comment: Why is $3 a string instead of an integer? Looks like an application issue, that creates an error in the database.

Comment: $3 is an integer or a string when the input is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As best as I can tell, you need this:

```
delivery_interval = (NULLIF($3::text, '')::integer)
```

First you need to cast the argument to text, so NULLIF is comparing like with like, then you cast the whole expression to integer, to match the column type.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF):

> The result has the same type as the first argument — but there is a
> subtlety. What is actually returned is the first argument of the
> implied `=` operator, and in some cases that will have been promoted
> to match the second argument's type. For example, `NULLIF(1, 2.2)`
> yields `numeric`, because there is no `integer = numeric` operator,
> only `numeric = numeric`.

So either your `$3` is `text` or is implicitly casted to `text` because of the implicit `=` `nullif()` causes. And that makes the result of `nullif()` a `text`.

You can try to explicitly cast the result of `nullif()`.

```
...
nullif($3, '')::integer
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is Postgres Then you have to use NULL For integer Datatype

update table_name set status =  'SUCCESS', column2 =  NULL where condition <>